# Image Source binding not working

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm binding the image `Source` to a `BitmapImage` in my code but it doesn't show up.

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="bleh.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="600">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Image x:Name="current" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding Picture}" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

and my cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Event implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public BitmapImage Picture { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("Images/xpto.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        this.Picture = new BitmapImage(uri);
        InitializeComponent();
        //setup();
    }
}
```

Strangely enough, the window opens with the size of the image, but I don't see the image. I've also tried assigning manually in the xaml and it works.

Doing `current.source="Images/xpto.jpg"` also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataContext of your view (MainWindow) is not set, so there is no "Picture" property to which to bind. If you want the view to bind to itself, add

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

to your MainWindow constructor.

Comment: Works, how do you do it in the xaml? i've tried `DataContext="MainWindow"` on the window tag and doesn't seem to work

Comment: Give your Window a Name (eg x:Name="Main"), and then use Source="{Binding Picture, ElementName=Main}"

Comment: Note also that although you CAN bind the DataContext of the Window (or any element inside it) in the Xaml, you'd have to bind to something that's already in the view (because, of course, you have no DataContext...)

Comment: You can do this xaml like so: `<Window [all your properties] DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">`. No need to add an x:Name. Works for Pages and stuff, too.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't implement the INotifyPropertyChanged for the property Picture:
public BitmapImage Picture { get; set; }
You've to do:

```
BitmapImage _picture;
public BitmapImage Picture {
get {return _picture;}
 set{
      _picture=value;
      OnPropertyChanged("Picture");
    }`
 }
```